# Is there a way to find out if a class has an overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I am writing a template class where I need a method to print out element class into `stdout`. But I am having a problem writing it - what if `cout <<` or `operator const char*()` is not defined or overloaded in my element class?

Is there a way to find it out to maybe throw an exception and not get compilation error?

Comment: You *prefer* having an exception over a compilation error? That contradicts the important principle of 'fail fast'. Compilation error is much safer than exceptions.

Comment: I do believe we are required to write a "fail-safe" code.

Comment: fail-safe code is using compilation errors and not exceptions. You should really resolve (or let the user of your library) resolve as much problems as possible during compilation and not on run-time.

Comment: There is no way to avoid compilation errors, you are supposed to get them while you are programming anyway, because anyone can make mistakes while writing. But compilation errors are easier to spot and fix than execution time/logical errors. And anyway, there is no way to continue developing anything if you do not fix compilation errors first.

Comment: The only legitimate reason I find to detect if a function/operator is present/callable is to provide for alternative actions if it isn't (or in any way make decisions) at *compile time*. Delaying anything for run time is nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the operator is not overloaded, your program can not compile. This is a compile time error and there is no way to delay that until runtime.

A way around would be to not use an operator, but a function pointer. If the operation is not supported, than the function pointer could be set to 0 which you can detect at runtime.

```
class A {
public:
    int q; // some data

    typedef std::function<void(std::ostream& os, const A&)> PrinterFunc;
    PrinterFunc func;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
        if(!a.func) {
            throw "Not supported";
        }
        func(os,a);
        return os;
    }
};

A a;
a.func = [](std::ostream& os, const A& a) { os << "hello " << a.q; }
std::cout << a << std::endl; // will print

A b;
std::cout << b << std::endl; // will throw
```

This example uses C++11 and `<functional>`. For C++03 you would have to use a "normal" function pointer.

Comment: @Testie While the answer is 100% correct, I really suggest you to reconsider your approach and do NOT favor exceptions over compilation errors.

Comment: @amit I read about that, but the task requires us to use exceptions. Thanks for the notice though.

Comment: @Testie: This probably depends on the application. Sometimes you can not know at compile time if something would/should work. But I agree, that in general you should push as much as possible to compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You might use some SFINAE to test if an (formatted) output operator exists:

```
#include <iostream>

// HasFormattedOutput
// ============================================================================

namespace HasFormattedOutput {

    namespace Detail
    {
        struct Failure{};
    }

    template<typename OutputStream, typename T>
    Detail::Failure operator << (OutputStream&, const T&);

    template<typename OutputStream, typename T>
    struct Result : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        ! std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<OutputStream&>() << std::declval<T>()),
            Detail::Failure
        >::value
    > {};
} // namespace HasFormattedOutput

template <typename T, typename OutputStream = std::ostream>
struct has_formatted_output : std::conditional<
    HasFormattedOutput::Result<OutputStream, T>::value,
    std::true_type,
    std::false_type>::type
{};

// Test
// ============================================================================

struct X {};
int main() {
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha);
    std::cout << has_formatted_output<const char*>() << '\n';
    std::cout << has_formatted_output<X>() << '\n';
}
```

(C++11)

Comment: Why `(*(OutputStream*)0)` and not just `std::declval<OutputStream&>()` ?

Comment: @iavr Old habit - Fixed